# change image every few seconds with a link - fade effect

Tags: jquery

Hi I found this code working good for change images every few seconds with a link included, but the problem is that I don't know how to add a fade effect to this code as I'm not a programmer, if someone could help me I will apreciate it so much, thx

```
   <script>
    var links = ["http://www.abc.com","http://www.def.com","http://www.ghi.com"];
    var images = ["http://www.abc.com/1.gif","http://www.def.com/2.gif","http://www.ghi.com/3gif"];
    var i = 0;
    var renew = setInterval(function(){
        if(links.length == i){
            i = 0;
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById("bannerImage").src = images[i]; 
        document.getElementById("bannerLink").href = links[i]; 
        i++;

    }
    },10000);
    </script>



<a id="bannerLink" href="http://www.abc.com" onclick="void window.open(this.href); return false;">
<img id="bannerImage" src="http://www.abc.com/1.gif" width="694" height="83" alt="some text">
</a>
```

PS sorry for my english

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if it resolved your question.  There should be a green check mark you can click to the left of the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have jQuery in your page

```
jQuery(function () {
    var links = ["http://www.abc.com", "http://www.def.com", "http://www.ghi.com"];
    var images = ["http://placehold.it/32/ff0000", "http://placehold.it/32/00ff00", "http://placehold.it/32/0000ff"];
    var i = 0, $link = $('#bannerLink'), $img = $('#bannerImage');
    setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        if (i >= links.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        $link.fadeOut(function () {
            $img.attr('src', images[i]);
            $link.attr('href', links[i]).fadeIn();
        })
    }, 2000)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/55Q6d/)